# Fine tuning addADX() to avoind truncating the trend curves

Tags: r, quantmod, trend

I am using the following code to look at the past 9 months of a stock.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AMZN")
candleChart(to.weekly(AMZN),multi.col=TRUE,theme="white",subset='last 9 months') 
addADX()
```

You can see that the red line is essentially not included in the plot because it mostly lies below the value of 20. I want to modify the Y axis range of `addADX` so that it always shows all three lines. How would it be possible?

Comment: Seems add parameter of `n=x` in `addADX` can change the y range. Try to select a reasonable `n`.

Comment: @Patric thanks, but what `n=x` does it moving the plot up or down. If so, `addADX(n=20)` is the best. However, the extremes of the plot are still not included. Is there a way to "squeeze" the plot or "stretch" the panel containing the plot vertically so that everything becomes visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input parameters of `addADX()` only control the computation of the directional movement index - not the graphical parameters which are set according to the average direction index.

A simple workaround to display the positive and negative direction index completely is to compute the directional movement index by yourself with `ADX()` from the `TTR` package and then add it to the previous chart with `addTA()`, which allows more customisation.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AMZN")
dat <- to.weekly(AMZN)
candleChart(dat, multi.col = TRUE, theme = "white", subset = "last 9 months")
adx <- ADX(HLC(dat), n = 14, maType = "EMA", wilder = TRUE)[, c("DIp", "DIn", "ADX")]
addTA(adx, col = c("green", "red", "blue"), lwd = c(1, 1, 2), legend = NULL)
```

[image: ADXaddTA]

Comment: Looks great, exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to remove the blue "average" line and just keep the green and red ones? I know this is not what `addADX()` does but just wanted to customize it and remove the blue line.

Comment: just remove the corresponding column and parameters: `addTA(adx[,c("DIp","DIn")], col = c("green", "red"), legend = NULL)`